# why this code does not work in visual studio code 2018

Tags: sql-server, node.js

```
function getCurrentId ()  {
    var data;
    var query = "INSERT INTO photos (path) VALUES (''); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id ";
    var request = new mssql.Request(connection);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.query(query, function(err, data) {
             resolve(data.recordset)
        });
    })
}

var main = async () =>{
    var quote =  await  getCurrentId enter code here();
    return quote; enter code here
};
```

i use in this code async await but .But this code is not correct.

```
var main = (async () =>{
              ^
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: The last time I received that error was because `async/await` wasn't supported in my node version yet. Which version are you using?

Comment: February 2018 (version 1.21)

Comment: No, the node version, not the IDE version

Comment: the node version  6.11.4

Comment: async await is not supported in node 6, either upgrade to ... 9.x? Maybe 8.x or use a transpiler like babel to support it